# Send object with sub-lists over TCP

Tags: c#, tcp

I need to send a Post request over TCP. The reason I am using TCP other than HTTP is time of waiting for a response. Using TCP I don't need to wait for a response.

I already have a away of sending GET requests with parameters. But now I need to send an object and this object has two lists of objects.

How do I send it?

```js
{
    "CustomerId" : 123,
    "CalendarYear" : 2023,
    "ExpensesA": [
        {"Id": "1", "Year": "2018", "Losses": "0", "Card": "0", "Taxes": "0"},
        {"Id": "2", "Year": "2019", "Losses": "0", "Card": "0", "Taxes": "0"},
        {"Id": "3", "Year": "2020", "Losses": "0", "Card": "0", "Taxes": "0"},
        {"Id": "4", "Year": "2021", "Losses": "0", "Card": "0", "Taxes": "0"}
    ],
    "ExpensesB": [
        {"Id": "1", "Year": "2018", "Losses": "0", "Card": "0", "Taxes": "0"},
        {"Id": "2", "Year": "2019", "Losses": "0", "Card": "0", "Taxes": "0"},
        {"Id": "3", "Year": "2020", "Losses": "0", "Card": "0", "Taxes": "0"},
        {"Id": "4", "Year": "2021", "Losses": "0", "Card": "0", "Taxes": "0"}
    ]    
}
```

**Obs.:
Here is the way I have it working (not my code).
This works calling an endpoint which is a HttpGet.
Now I need to call a HttpPost endpoint.
So, I wonder if there is a way of managing that to send an object(*Body*), instead of just parameters.
But I don't know how I could do it.**

```cs
    using var tcp = new TcpClient("localhost", 12345);

    using var stream = tcp.GetStream();

    tcp.SendTimeout = 500;
    tcp.ReceiveTimeout = 1000;

    var resourceUri = new StringBuilder($"/Endpoint/{relativeUrl}");

    resourceUri.Append($"?id={personId}");
    resourceUri.Append($"&year={year}");

    var builder = new StringBuilder();

    builder.AppendLine($"GET {resourceUri} HTTP/1.1");
    builder.AppendLine("Host: host.com");
    builder.AppendLine("Connection: close");
    builder.AppendLine();

    var header = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(builder.ToString());

    await stream.WriteAsync(header, 0, header.Length);
```

Comment: _"How do I send it?"_ - you tell us. _You_ invented the protocol. There are no verbs like GET or POST in TCP. If you have that, then **you created your application protocol on top of TCP**. And we have no clue how it works.

Comment: When I said Get and Post, it is because the code I got, seems to mimic a Get Request, using TCP, instead of Http. Now, I need to adapt this logic(or other), to request to a Post endpoint.

Comment: Ah. Ok. That's basically explicit http and ignoring the answer. You can refer to the respective [rfcs](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-9.5) in that case. HttpClient would be more convenient, but alas.